# Quiero saber si es posible cuadrar un <progress> bar dentro de <td>

Tags: html, css, progressbar

Tengo un bloqueo con mi diseño de CV, quiero cuadrar una barra de progreso dentro de un dato de tabla y que esta la rellene por completo, solo puedo ponerla dentro pero lo logro rellenar la `<td>` con la `<progress>`

[image: F]

[image: Asi quiero que se vea (lo edite en paint)]

HTML

```
<div id="skills">
    <h2 class="stittle"> Skills </h2>
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>Programming Lang.</b></td>
            <td align="center">Python</td>
            <td align="center">Arduino</td>
            <td align="center">JavaScript</td>
            <td align="center">HTML</td>
            <td id="top-right" align="center">CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>Skill Level</b></td>
            <td align="center"><progress id="P-Py" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
            <td align="center"><progress id="P-Ar" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
            <td align="center"><progress id="P-Ja" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
            <td align="center"><progress id="P-HT" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
            <td align="center"><progress id="P-CS" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="bottom-left" align="center"><b>knowledge</b></td>
            <td align="center">Img Edition</td>
            <td align="center">Video Edition</td>
            <td align="center">Microsoft Office</td>
            <td align="center">English Lang.</td>
            <td align="center">CCTV</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

esta es la parte de CSS, la verdad estuve probando bastantes cosas y formas diferente pero no llego al resultado que deseo.

CSS

```
#skills{
    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

table{
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: grey;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 26px;
    border-top-right-radius: 26px;
}
td{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px;
    border-color: aqua;
    background-color: rgb(230, 255, 255);
}
td#P-Py{
    nose que hacer aca T·T
}
td#top-right{
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
td#bottom-left{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

No se si es posible o no lo que quiero hacer, pero en otras paginas lo he visto y por eso recurro a ustedes, necesito sabes si se puede lograr, y si se puede... como?

Ayudita porfis jeje

Comment: Buen día, cómo quieres que sea tu resultado esperado? a que te refieres con cuadrar y que se rellene por completo? no logro entender del todo bien...

Comment: Voy a agregar una imagen

Comment: Dale un estilo a los td donde pones el progress para que no tengan padding

Answer (score 2):

Primero, a tus `td` les quité el `padding` para que tu `<progress>` ocupe todo el espacio del `td`:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center"><b>Skill Level</b></td>
  <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-Py" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
  <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-Ar" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
  <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-Ja" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
  <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-HT" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
  <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-CS" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
</tr>
```

Luego, revisando un poco [**este artículo**](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/), podrías modificar los estilos de tu `<progress>` de esta manera:

```css
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #eee;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #3f48cc;
}
```

En donde:

- `::-webkit-progress-bar`: Personalizo el fondo de la barra.
- `::-webkit-progress-value`: Personalizo a la barra que aumenta depende al valor.

Una imagen para que se entienda mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por cierto, `progress` sería **todo** tu `progress-bar`, en lo que le estoy quitando los estilos por defecto para modificarlos, con estas propiedades:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

Código completo:

```css
#skills {
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5);
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 26px;
  border-top-right-radius: 26px;
}

td {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: aqua;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 255);
}

progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #eee;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #3f48cc;
}

td#top-right {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

td#bottom-left {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
  <h2 class="stittle"> Skills </h2>
  <table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><b>Programming Lang.</b></td>
      <td align="center">Python</td>
      <td align="center">Arduino</td>
      <td align="center">JavaScript</td>
      <td align="center">HTML</td>
      <td id="top-right" align="center">CSS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><b>Skill Level</b></td>
      <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-Py" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
      <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-Ar" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
      <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-Ja" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
      <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-HT" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
      <td style="padding: 0px !important;"><progress id="P-CS" max="100" value="50"></progress></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="bottom-left" align="center"><b>knowledge</b></td>
      <td align="center">Img Edition</td>
      <td align="center">Video Edition</td>
      <td align="center">Microsoft Office</td>
      <td align="center">English Lang.</td>
      <td align="center">CCTV</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/poOyYRe).

Comment: Esos `-webkit-` funcionan en todos los navegadores? Entiendo que no.

Comment: @Alfabravo solo Chrome y Safari creo, pero se puede usar el prefijo correspondiente para que lo reconozca el navegador, por ejemplo `::-moz-` de Mozilla, `::-ms-` de Microsoft, etc...

Comment: Importante aclaración porque no sabemos en qué entorno o qué requerimiento no funcional tiene el OP :)